# Function for modulus addition of numbers (like degrees)

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-language

I want to cycle through 0-3 values to any direction (adding or subtracting 1).

Basically I'd like to do [modular addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), like with degrees:

```
320° + 45° = 5°
0° - 2° = 358°
```

I've found a [`clamp(val, min, max)`](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/maths/real%20valued%20functions/clamp.html) and [Modulo](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/001_gml%20language%20overview/401_04_expressions.html) but those are different.

I've constructed `((n % max) + max) % max` already but I was wondering if such function already available.

Comment: I know that GM2 handles degrees < 0 and > 360 just fine in most cases, I'm looking for some general solution.

Answer (score 1):

So far just created a script.

`overflow.gml`:

```
/// @arg val
/// @arg maximum

var val = argument0;
var maximum = argument1 + 1;

return ((val % maximum) + maximum) % maximum;
```